# How do I list all products in ascending order in Magento?

Tags: products, product-collection, sorting

I try to list all product names in a store, so I try the following code.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(5000)->setCurPage(1);

$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    echo $product->getName();
    echo "<br>";
}
```

This gives the following result.

[image: Without sort]

After that I try to sort this. The code is:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addAttributeToSelect('*')->setPageSize(5000)->setCurPage(1);
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('status', Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Status::STATUS_ENABLED);

foreach ($collection as $product) {
    $pro[] = $product->getName();
}

sort($pro);

foreach ($pro as $pr) {
    echo  $pr; echo"<br>";
}
```

This gives the following result.

[image: With Sort]

It gives two lists in ascending order.

Why does it behave like this?

I need only one list with ascending order for that. What should I do?

Answer (score 6):

The reason you got two lists with ascending order is because of PHP `sort()` function. The default sorting behavior for this function is `non-natural ordering`, so it gives you unpredictable results. Try `natcasesort()` instead of `sort()`. See more detail about PHP `sort()` on below link:

> http://php.net/manual/en/function.sort.php

**OR**

try to sorting your collection through Magento `addAttributeToSort` collection method, see below code for reference:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
```

Hope this will clear your doubt.

Answer (score 3):

Try this code :

```
<?


$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
->addAttributeToSelect('*')
->addAttributeToSort('name','ASC') // for name
->setPageSize(5000)->setCurPage(1);

?>
```

For other field use : `->addAttributeToSort('field','ASC')`
Hope it will work for you.